# Retrieve a value from an array and make a condition

Tags: php, arrays, conditional-statements

I have the following code that I am using on WordPress:

```php
if($terms && !is_wp_error($terms) ) {
  $colors = array();
  foreach ($terms as $term) {
    $colors[] = '\'' . $term->slug . '\'';
  }
}

print_r(array_values($thePack));
```

The variable `$color` now is a basic Array, which `print_r` displays like this:

```php
Array (
    [0] => 'white'
    [1] => 'green'
)
```

I'd like to make a condition in order recognize whether the array has or not a specific value, for example:

```php
if(in_array('white', $colors) {
  echo "This is white";
}
```

However, it is not working at all, because the `in_array` does not recognize the value in the array!

How could I make the condition work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your array values (the color names) include single quotes, which you need to include when you search for a value:

```
if(in_array("'white'", $colors) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Sniper mode activate!

Answer (score 0):

Why not do something like this:

```
while(list($key, $value) = each($array)){
    if($value == 'white'){
       echo 'this is white';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are escaping the color into the array. Instead of using

```
$colors[] = '\''.$term->slug.'\''
```

Just do

```
$colors[] = $term->slug
```

And when you output the slug to the web page or the database, then you escape it.

Comment: That would works, however, I need the '\'' for best querying the values on my `WP_query`!

Comment: Alex's answer works fine but is not a best practice, it's like saying, hey, if i have a white color in my whitish array of colors then make it work. You should escape your slugs upon querying by using an array_map or else you could create yourself more problems later on because of this strategy. Trust me, i've seen this kind of thing happen before.